# How to select an option in a lightning-select in JavaScript

Tags: lightning-web-components

I would like to change the selected value of a lightning-select component via JavaScript.  Not on LWR.  Is this possible? It seems not to be.

Things I've tried include:

```
* this.template.querySelector(".mySelector").value = <thevalue>;
* this.template.querySelector(".mySelector").selectedIndex = 0;
* this.template.querySelector(".mySelector").options[0].selected = true;
* <lightning-select value={myValue}></lightning-select> in the HTML, 
then changing this.myValue in the Javascript.
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use a variable for the value. The key is you need to set it to the new value in the event handler when the value changes.  Then, when you set it back to the value you really want, the framework realizes there's a new value and makes the change in the DOM.

```
<lightning-select
  value={durationValue}
  label="Some label"
  options={durationOptions}
  onchange={handleDurationSelectChanged}
></lightning-select>
```

In Javascript

```
  handleDurationSelectChanged(event) {
    this.durationValue = event.detail.value;
  }
```

Then to change the selected value at any time

```
this.durationValue = <some value>;
```